# How to load an image from an storage(MinIO) using GetObjectAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, minio

im trying to load an image from my storage MinIO, all the connections are working right, but im new to C# and not figuring out how to do it.

This image gonna be printed on a HTML, so i dont want to download it or anything, just print in the screen.

How you can see, im getting the object with the GetObjectArgs() method, just like they Docs.

```
GetObjectArgs getObjectArgs = new GetObjectArgs()
                                    .WithBucket(myBucket)
                                    .WithObject(myObject)
                                    .WithCallbackStream((stream) =>
                                    {
                                        stream.CopyTo(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
                                    });

object objectData = await minio.GetObjectAsync(getObjectArgs);
```

This method returns the object, so when i print this i have the following response:

```
{
"objectName": "mylogo.png",
"size": 18028,
"lastModified": "2023-11-28T15:27:14-03:00",
"eTag": "--SECRET--",
"contentType": "image/png",
"metaData": {
"Content-Type": "image/png"
},
"versionId": null,
"deleteMarker": false,
"extraHeaders": {
"Server": "openresty",
"Date": "Wed, 29 Nov 2023 14:11:31 GMT",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
"Vary": "Origin",
"X-Amz-Id-2": "--SECRET--",
"X-Amz-Request-Id": "--SECRET--",
"X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
"X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
"X-Served-By": "--SECRET--"
},
"taggingCount": null,
"archiveStatus": null,
"expires": null,
"replicationStatus": null,
"objectLockMode": null,
"objectLockRetainUntilDate": null,
"legalHoldEnabled": null
}
```

**My question is**, what methods i have to use to convert this object as an imagem on my screen?
Convert the object to Base64 and to image after? I really dont know, anything work till now and find nothing. Or maybe this doesnt make sense at all?

Im already try using the method PresignedUrl and create a temp access URL, it works fine, but it seems wrong to me, because it will be a lot of calls to this objects/project.

See some examples of peoples using MemoryStream so o try this, but i keeps alerting ResponseStream, it simply doesnt recognize it.

```
using (var responseStream = objectData.ResponseStream)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

I was hopint so find something like:

`Convert.ToImage(objectData)`

Comment: Presigned URLs are fine for this task.

Answer (score 0):

U can access your image with minio url

minioUrl:9000/bucketName/mylogo.png

9000 is a default port, if u have some custom one u can replace. Also bucketName should be replaced with your actual value

Comment: Thanks for the awnser!

And the credencials? minIO isn't public

Comment: `var memStream = new MemoryStream();

GetObjectArgs getObjectArgs = new GetObjectArgs()
                                    .WithBucket(myBucket)
                                    .WithObject(myObject)
                                    .WithCallbackStream((stream) =>
                                    {
                                        stream.CopyTo(memStream);
                                    });

object objectData = await minio.GetObjectAsync(getObjectArgs);

return memStream;`